# Do we have 'groupby' clause in Neo4j?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, neo4j, graphql, cypher, graph-databases

I have written the below query to retrieve `movie` and corresponding `rating`:

```
match (rvwr:Person)-[r:REVIEWED]->(m:Movie)
where m.released > 2003
return m.title, sum(r.rating)/count(r) as rating
```

I want to confirm if there is a need to use anything similar to `groupby clause`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such 'group by' clause in neo4j cypher.  Sum is an aggregate function and m.title is not. So cypher will use title as a group by key. Below is the documentation about it.

> https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/